# Customize date format

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, regional-settings

I have a Lumia 950XL running Windows 10 Mobile on the Windows Insider Fast Track, with 10.0.14376.0 installed.

I'd like to customize my date format to be yyyy-MM-dd, like every sane person would.

Under "Region", I can specify "Canada" as the region, then "English (Canada)" as the "regional format".  This shows the settings as:

```
Calendar: Gregorian Calendar
Date: June 30, 2016
Time: 12:36 PM
Currency: $
```

Below the "Regional format example" is a link -> "Change formats".  This used to allow customization of the date format; however it no longer does that on my phone, electing simply to display a disabled drop-down that would (if it wasn't disabled) allow selecting the type of calendar you'd like to use.

Is there some other setting applet I can use to customize my date format?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a problem with the insider build? Cause if it's a common problem you have to wait unil MS fixes it. Hopefully in next build as public release is only a month away.

Comment: @KolappanNathan - it most likely *is* a problem with the insider build.  I am wondering if perhaps I'm just not looking in the correct location.

Comment: Did it work in your region previously? For my region (India) it is always disabled.